# Java generics - gain access to parameters

Tags: java, generics

I have next code:

```
class iCache<K,V> implements Map<Object, Object>
{
...//Code
}
```

How can I get the class name of K and V?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you extend `iCache` and want to obtain the typer parameters you used to declare the subclass (like below):

```
class someCache extends iCache<Integer,Long> {
//...
}
```

You can find out those parameters at runtime using the following ([source](http://community.jboss.org/wiki/GenericDataAccessObjects)):

```
Class clazz = ((ParameterizedType) getClass()
                       .getGenericSuperclass()).getActualTypeArguments()[0];
```

If you provide the parameters at instantiating like this

```
iCache<Integer,Long> cache = new iCache<Integer,Long>();
```

then you are out of luck ([more info](http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=208860)).

Comment: My problem that if i have


`iCache<Integer,Integer> cache = new iCache<Integer,Integer>(20);`

i can put everything such as


`cache.put(0, "test");`


 I really don't know how to fix that.

Comment: @ExR: You need to implement `Map<K,V>` and not `Map<Object,Object>`!

Answer (score 7):

You can't, the compiler performs type erasure at compile time.  In other words, the K and V type parameters are purely a compile time notion, they aren't accessible at runtime.

What you can do is to grab the class of the key/values in your custom Map type at runtime.

Comment: Worth noting that the class of keys/values at runtime can be different from the actual parameters (it can be the subclass of K and V).

Answer (score 5):

You can't.  Java generics don't work that way.  At runtime, there is no class-specific information available (this is known as `erasure`).  If you really need this information, you will have to pass in e.g. `Class` objects.

Answer (score 2):

The types will get erased. Pass in Class and Class as args into the constructor to pass through your raw types. Store as fields. Note: your patameterisation is bad anyway: you need to pass K and V to Map as well, or you'll give yourself more pain.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can, call the getClass() method on the key and value